# Swift - Accessing decoded frames with AVPlayerItemVideoOutput: outputMediaDataWillChange is not called

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have an app which plays a video chosen from the user's library. What I intend for the app to be able to do eventually is to render an overlay onto the video (whilst it is playing) and then output the result to a new media file. In order to do this, I need to capture the decoded frames so that I can render this overlay and output to a file once the video playback has ended.

This is my first app using AVFoundation and I have spent a day or two trying to find out how to achieve this through google, and Apple documentation, and I thought I had something in the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` object. However, the delegate callback is never executed.

I discovered that `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` must be created *after* the `AVPlayerItem` is in status `readyToPlay`. So, in the initialiser for my `PlayerUIView` I add an observer to the AVPlayerItem in order to watch its status.

```
init(frame: CGRect, url: Binding<URL?>) {
        _url = url
        // Setup the player
        player = AVPlayer(url: url.wrappedValue!)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        
        //displayLink = CADisplayLink()
        
        // Setup looping
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                               name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: player.currentItem)
        
        player.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
        
        // Start the movie
        player.play()
    }
```

I have a CADisplayLink being created in the middle - commented out - because I saw that it could be used somehow for this but not exactly sure how or what it's supposed to do. Also concerned from the name that it gets frames from the displayed video rather than from the actual decoded video frames which is what I wanted.

When the status is set to `readyToPlay` for the first time, I create and add the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput`.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let item = object as? AVPlayerItem {
            if item.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay && item.outputs.count == 0 {
                let settings = [ String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB ]
                let output = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: settings)
                
                output.setDelegate(PlayerOutput(output: output), queue: DispatchQueue(label: ""))
                
                player.currentItem?.add(output)
            }
        }
    }
```

On the delegate `PlayerOutput` I am expecting to be notified when new frames are available. At which point I would access the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` object to access the pixel buffer.

```
class PlayerOutput : NSObject, AVPlayerItemOutputPullDelegate {
        
        func outputMediaDataWillChange(_ sender: AVPlayerItemOutput) {
            let videoOutput = sender as! AVPlayerItemVideoOutput
            let newPixelBuff = videoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 10))
        }
    }
```

However, this callback is never made. I set a breakpoint in the code and it is never hit. From the naming and similar code elsewhere in AVFoundation I assumed it would be hit for every new frame so I could access the frame in the buffer, but I'm not seeing anything happen. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

I have a feeling I'm not quite using/understanding these classes right and what they are for, but it is similar in nomenclature to the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` etc. classes which I have managed to implement successfully elsewhere in the app, they just don't seem to work quite the same. Very difficult to find any examples doing what I want to do with the AVPlayer.

**EDIT:** Working Example of current code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CustomCameraPhotoView: View {

    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var showingCustomCamera = false
    @State private var showImagePicker = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    @State private var url: URL?

    var body: some View {
                ZStack {
                    if url != nil
                    {
                        PlayerView(url: $url)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showImagePicker = true
                            }) {
                            Text("Select a Video").foregroundColor(.white).font(.headline)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker,
                   onDismiss: loadImage) {
                    PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image, url: self.$url)
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.leading).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.trailing)
    }
    func loadImage() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
    }
}

struct PlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var url: URL?
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiView: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() ->  PlayerCoordinator{
    //Make Coordinator which will commnicate with the    ImagePickerViewController
        PlayerCoordinator()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let view = PlayerUIView(frame: .zero, url: $url)
        let controller = PlayerController()
        controller.view = view
        
        return controller
    }
}

class PlayerCoordinator : NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
}

class PlayerController: UIViewController {
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .all
    }
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var playerOutput = PlayerOutput()
    private let _myVideoOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoFrames", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)
    
    var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
    var player: AVPlayer
    
    @Binding var url: URL?

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    init(frame: CGRect, url: Binding<URL?>) {
        _url = url
        // Setup the player
        player = AVPlayer(url: url.wrappedValue!)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        
        let settings = [ String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA ]
        let output = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: settings)
        
        output.setDelegate(self.playerOutput, queue: self._myVideoOutputQueue)
        
        player.currentItem?.add(output)
        
        //displayLink = CADisplayLink()
        
        // Setup looping
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                               name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: player.currentItem)
        
        player.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)

        // Start the movie
        player.play()
    }
    
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let item = object as? AVPlayerItem {
            if item.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay && item.outputs.count == 0 {
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc
    func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
        self.url = nil
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
    class PlayerOutput : NSObject, AVPlayerItemOutputPullDelegate {
        
        func outputMediaDataWillChange(_ sender: AVPlayerItemOutput) {
            let videoOutput = sender as! AVPlayerItemVideoOutput
            let newPixelBuff = videoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 10))
        }
    }
}

struct ImagePicker : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isShown : Bool
    @Binding var image : Image?
    @Binding var url : URL?
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>)
    {
       //Update UIViewcontrolleer Method
    }
    func makeCoordinator() ->  ImagePickerCoordinator{
    //Make Coordinator which will commnicate with the    ImagePickerViewController
        ImagePickerCoordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image, url: $url)
    }
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController
    {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        picker.videoQuality = .typeHigh
         return picker
    }
}

class ImagePickerCoordinator : NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
@Binding var isShown : Bool
@Binding var image : Image?
    @Binding var url: URL?
    init(isShown : Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<Image?>, url: Binding<URL?>) {
      _isShown = isShown
      _image = image
      _url = url
   }
//Selected Image
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL]   as! URL
    url = uiImage
//image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
   isShown = false
}
//Image selection got cancel
   func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
   isShown = false
   }
}

struct PhotoCaptureView: View {
   @Binding var showImagePicker : Bool
   @Binding var image : Image?
    @Binding var url : URL?
 
   var body: some View {
    ImagePicker(isShown: $showImagePicker, image: $image, url: $url)
   }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomCameraPhotoView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** You were right in suspecting `outputMediaDataWillChange` is a complete different beast than `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. It is not called per frame but rather indicates some player state changes (it is a bit unclear to me what cases exactly). There are (at least) two options for reading and modifying the video output.

1. You can add a `videoComposition` to the current `playerItem` in which you can use CoreImage tools to adjust the video (e.g. add an overlay). In this example I applied a simple blur filter to the output, but CoreImage allows you to do much more complicated stuff.

```
let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
if let playerItem = player.currentItem {
    let asset = playerItem.asset
    
    playerItem.videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset) { (filteringRequest) in
        let source = filteringRequest.sourceImage
        blurFilter?.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        
        filteringRequest.finish(with: blurFilter?.outputImage ?? source, context: nil)
    }
}
```

2. If you need the actual pixelbuffers, you were on the right track with `CADisplayLink`. Display link allows you to synchronise operations with the display refresh rate. You can grab the frames from your video output in the following manner:

```
lazy var displayLink: CADisplayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkDidRefresh(link:)))

init(frame: CGRect, url: Binding<URL?>) {
    ...
    // activate the displayLink
    displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
    ...
}

@objc func displayLinkDidRefresh(link: CADisplayLink) {
    guard let videoOutput = self.videoOutput else { return }
    
    let itemTime = player.currentTime()
    if videoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime) {
        var presentationItemTime: CMTime = .zero
        if let pixelBuffer = videoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime, itemTimeForDisplay: &presentationItemTime) {
            
            // process the pixelbuffer here
        }
    }
}
```

**Complete minimal example:**

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CustomCameraPhotoView: View {

    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var showingCustomCamera = false
    @State private var showImagePicker = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    @State private var url: URL?

    var body: some View {
                ZStack {
                    if url != nil {
                        PlayerView(url: $url)
                    } else {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.showImagePicker = true
                            }) {
                            Text("Select a Video")
                                .font(.headline)
                        }
                    }
                }   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker,
                           onDismiss: loadImage) {
                            PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image, url: self.$url)
                    }
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.leading).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.trailing)
    }
    
    func loadImage() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
    }
}

struct PlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var url: URL?
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiView: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let view = PlayerUIView(frame: .zero, url: $url)
        let controller = PlayerController()
        controller.view = view
        
        return controller
    }
}

class PlayerController: UIViewController {
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool { false }
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { .all }
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private let _myVideoOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "VideoFrames", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)
    
    lazy var displayLink: CADisplayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkDidRefresh(link:)))
    var player: AVPlayer
    var videoOutput: AVPlayerItemVideoOutput
    
    @Binding var url: URL?

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    init(frame: CGRect, url: Binding<URL?>) {
        _url = url
        // Setup the player
        player = AVPlayer(url: url.wrappedValue!)
        
        let settings = [ String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA ]
        let output = AVPlayerItemVideoOutput(pixelBufferAttributes: settings)
        self.videoOutput = output
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        
        attachVideoComposition()
        
        player.currentItem?.add(output)
        displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)

        // Start the movie
        player.play()
    }
    
    private func attachVideoComposition() {
        let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        if let playerItem = player.currentItem {
            let asset = playerItem.asset
            
            playerItem.videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset) { (filteringRequest) in
                let source = filteringRequest.sourceImage
                blurFilter?.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                
                // Apply CoreImage provessing here
                
                filteringRequest.finish(with: blurFilter?.outputImage ?? source, context: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let item = object as? AVPlayerItem {
            if item.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay && item.outputs.count == 0 {
                
            }
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
    @objc func displayLinkDidRefresh(link: CADisplayLink) {
        let itemTime = player.currentTime()
        if videoOutput.hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime) {
            var presentationItemTime: CMTime = .zero
            if let pixelBuffer = videoOutput.copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime: itemTime, itemTimeForDisplay: &presentationItemTime) {
                
                // process the pixelbuffer here
                print(pixelBuffer)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ImagePicker : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isShown : Bool
    @Binding var image : Image?
    @Binding var url : URL?
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
       //Update UIViewcontrolleer Method
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerCoordinator{
        ImagePickerCoordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image, url: $url)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        picker.videoQuality = .typeHigh
        return picker
    }
}

class ImagePickerCoordinator : NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    @Binding var isShown : Bool
    @Binding var image : Image?
    @Binding var url: URL?
    
    init(isShown : Binding<Bool>, image: Binding<Image?>, url: Binding<URL?>) {
      _isShown = isShown
      _image = image
      _url = url
   }

   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
        url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL

        isShown = false
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        isShown = false
    }
}

struct PhotoCaptureView: View {
    @Binding var showImagePicker : Bool
    @Binding var image           : Image?
    @Binding var url             : URL?
 
    var body: some View {
        ImagePicker(isShown: $showImagePicker, image: $image, url: $url)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomCameraPhotoView()
    }
}
```

**Original answer:**
Delegates are always(?) defined as weak members. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritemvideooutput/1385827-delegate). Your `PlayerOutput` object will have exited scope before the delegate can be called. Make the `PlayerOutput` member of some object that is alive during playback and your code should work as is.

Comment: Funny you should bring that up because I tried this after creating the question and the delegate is still not called.

Comment: Bummer. It is a mistake, so you might want to fix this in the question. I’ll have another look later.

Comment: I have added a working minimum viable example of the code to the question; with this change already made.

Comment: My mistake, the question triggered me, but I stopped looking when I found the delegate mistake. The `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` delegate is a bit misleading. I remember I initially made the same mistake in thinking it should be used for accessing the frames. I've added two methods you can use for accessing the video frames from the AVPlayer.

Comment: Thank you, this works!

Now, my problem is that since this is a "Display Link" I am getting a downscaled version of the Pixel Buffers. 1280x720 for a 3840x2160 video. Hmm....

Comment: I don't think DisplayLink has anything to do with that, it merely is a callback that fires with the update rate of the screen. I suspect the issue is with the [image picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716000/avplayeritemvideooutput-copypixelbuffer-always-returns-1280x720)